# Unique Constraint over values of two domain classes in Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, constraints, unique

I have two domain classes. One is :

```
 class User {
    String login
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String address
    String email

    static constraints = {
        login blank:false, size:5..15,matches:/[\S]+/, unique:true
        password blank:false, size:5..15,matches:/[\S]+/
        firstName blank:false
        lastName blank:false
        email email: true
    }
 }
```

And other is

```
class AddWebsite {

String website
User user
static constraints = { 
                     website blank:false 
                     website(unique: ['user'])
                     }
}
```

I am working with MongoDB at the backend. I need that for a particular login value, all siteURL values should be unique. Ex: login = abc@gmail.com. Then this user can have all unique url only in the database. But same urls can exist for different users. How do I do that using the unique constraint or any other approach?

Comment: does the `SiteURL` contain other fields?

Comment: No. The only field in that is siteURL.

Comment: so, you don't really need to wrap them into an object. default mongo primitive collection type would do just fine here

Comment: Thanks. I am new to mongo and grails both. So I am trying to figure out how to do it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked. I was getting the user cannot be null error while entering the website though it was not being validated in the AddWebsite domain class. I made the following changes and got it to work:

```
class AddWebsite{
    String website
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static constraints = {
        website( url:true, unique: ['user'])
    }
}
```

And in my controller also, I set the value of the user object to the session variable:

```
def addWebsites() {
    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        def w = new AddWebsite()
        w.properties[
                    'website'
                ] = params
        w.user = session["user"]                       //modified to make it work
     if(w.save()) {
            render view:'addWebsites', model:[message: "Successfully saved"]
        }
        else {
            return [addWebsite:w]
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should be able to place unique constraint on the `AddWebsite` domain class such as this:

```
class AddWebsite {
  String website
  User user
  static constraints = { 
    website(blank:false, unique: ['user'])
  }
}
```

This will ensure that each website is unique in the database per user. Notice that multiple constraints are applied to the property website.

**edited** to match updated question.

Comment: I added this constraint. It still allows me to add the same url through same userid.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the updated code. This type of unique constraint should work. Something else is going on.

Comment: Ok I just updated it. I just changed the name siteURL to website. If you can figure out it would be a great help. I am stuck at it for 2 days now :(

Comment: Updated my answer. You were close, but not quite there.

Comment: I tried this as well. Now it doesn't let me add any values(whether unique or repetitive) and keeps saying "user cannot be null".

Comment: `user nullable:true` if that should be allowed

Answer (score 1):

Use embedded sub-documents to store `SiteURL` instances right inside the `User`. Then you define the collection to be a Set, which makes sure, all it's entries are unique. If you want to use the default mongo collection types or want to persist the order, define an interceptor like:

```
def beforeSave = {
  urls = urls.unique() 
}
```

UPDATE:
If your urls are plain strings, use the default primitive collection (no `hasMany`):

```
class User {
  String login
  //...
  Set urls = new HashSet()
}
```