# Grails Unique constraint for several Domain Classes

Tags: mongodb, class, grails, unique

Is there any way to make two domain classes' values unique. 
Example:

```
Class A { String username }
Class B { int roll_no }
```

I want the combination of username and roll_no to be unique in the database.

I am using MongoDB in the backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique Constraint over values of two domain classes in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244457/unique-constraint-over-values-of-two-domain-classes-in-grails)

Comment: Thanks Joshua but I tried those approaches. Didnt work. That's my post only :D

Comment: which combination exactly do you mean? how are you persisting it?

Comment: @injecteer for every username should have only distinct roll_no values. Like: 
abc 1, 
abc 2,
abc 3 are allowed but abc 1, abc 1 are not allowed

Comment: How is class A related to Class B?